# Why is an address of an int able to be treated as a pointer to an int?

Tags: c, pointers, reference

I'm very confused why this code works. I was taught that a pointer was a "capsule" holding the address of something. So the `swapnum` function should be expecting one of those "capsules", not the actual address of the int. Is it creating a temporary pointer and setting it to that address? If that's the case, then what would be happening if I passed a pointer in by reference such as `int * c = &a;` `swapnum (&c...`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swapnum(int *i, int *j) {
  int temp = *i;
  *i = *j;
  *j = temp;
}

int main(void) {
  int a = 10;
  int b = 20;

  swapnum(&a, &b);
  printf("A is %d and B is %d\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: An `int *` points to `int`. `&c` would be of type `int **` or a pointer to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! All of your answers helped a lot and I fully understand it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pointer` is just another word for address.  There's nothing really magic about it, it is just a variable that contains a number, that number being the memory address of the thing it points to.

In your example, memory might look like this:

```
0x00001004 - 10         # a
0x00001008 - 20         # b
0x0000100C - 0x0001004  # i
0x00001010 - 0x0001008  # j
0x00001014 - 00         # temp
```

`i` and `j` are both `int*` which means they contain an address that contains an integar.  The code `*i` says "return whatever value is at the address in `i` and assume it is an `int`.

So if you look at your `swapnum`, here's what happens:

```
int temp = *i;
# take the value at 0x0001004 (10) and place it in 0x00001014

*i = *j;
# place the value at 0x0001008 (20) and place it in 0x00001004

*j = temp;
# place the value at 0x0001014 (10) and place it in 0x0001008
```

After which memory looks like this:

```
0x00001004 - 20         # a
0x00001008 - 10         # b
0x0000100C - 0x0001004  # i
0x00001010 - 0x0001008  # j
0x00001014 - 10         # temp
```

You could certainly do this:

```
int* c = &a;
swapnum(c, &b);
```

All you are doing is getting the address of `a`, putting it in `c` and then passing it into `swapnum`, which expects an address.  A pointer is just an address.

Answer (score 2):

The address of an object *is* a pointer to the object! That's really all there is to pointers, actually: they now at which address an object lives. The whole point of using addresses instead of objects is that using addresses you have the same object.

Answer (score 1):

`&item` returns a pointer to `item`.

Also, on all modern architectures I know of a pointer is simply the address of the item.

If you make a pointer to a pointer and pass it to swapnum one of two things will happen:

1. Your compiler will complain because the pointer is of type int**, not int*
2. You will swap the values of the pointers. At least if a pointer is the same size as an integer

Comment: A pointer is always the address of an item, on any architecture whatsoever. This is the definition of a "pointer"

Comment: Actually, on 8-bit and 16-bit x86 pointers were somewhat more complex. You had 'near' and 'far' pointers, the far ones included segment and address, while the near ones were just the address. A near and a far pointer could point to the same data while having different values.

Comment: But then what if I'm passing a pointer by reference into a function expecting a pointer? I'm really passing a pointer to a pointer? In that case, why can I access memory in the function like normal with `a->data`, instead of `a->pointer->data`?

Comment: A pointer is just a flat datatype, like an `int`.  Passing a pointer by reference is no difference than passing an `int` by reference.  In both cases, you are passing the address of the item.  In other words, if you pass a pointer to int by reference, you are passing in the address of the address of the integer.

Comment: So if I have a pointer to an object, and I pass that pointer into a function, there is no way to change the actual value of that pointer, only the object itself, correct?

Comment: Well. Yes. Or, you are free to change the pointer, but it will only be changed in your function.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`you're using the *address-of* `&` operator to pass to `swapnum`the addresses of `a` and `b`.

The value of a pointer actually *is* an address. There's no "capsule" at all! (Maybe, it's even easier to think of them as plain addresses without capsules!).

If you did `int *c = &a` you could pass c to `swapnum()`instead of `&a`and it would work just fine. You can't pass `&c`because you'd be passing an `int **`, while the function is expecting an `int *`.

Answer (score 1):

`&a` is an expression which is evaluated as the `a's` address in memory. This value must be stored in a variable of type pointer. For example:

```
int* i = &a;
```

Here, `i` is a variable of type `int pointer` which acts as a container, a capsule, for the value assigned to it. However, this capsule doesn't keep the `a` value itself; it keeps the `&a` value. Also, being a capsule is a direct result of being a variable in general; not necessarily because of being a variable of `pointer` type.

Now, this statement:

```
swapnum(&a, &b);
```

does a very normal job of coping the arguments into some local variables - a normal pass-by-value function call. In this case, what actually happens is it copies the `&a` value, i.e. the `a's` address, into a local variable `i`, which of course, is required to be defined of type `int pointer`.

if you defined:

```
int * c = &a;
```

and then call:

```
swapnum (&c...
```

that wouldn't work because `c` would be a variable of type `int pointer`; `&c`, then, would be the address of such a variable; Therefore, the local variable type `i` which would contain this address should have been defined as a container for such type of value; i.e. it should have been defined as a variable of type pointer to the address of an `int pointer` or `int **`

Such a function call without changing the function correspondingly would certainly result in a compiler time error.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a statically typed language. It means that every expression has one specific type known compile-time. The C++ standard tells us that if the expression expr is of built-in type T then the expression &expr is of type T* (pointer to T). That's all...